# Change JButton Color on ActionPerformed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

Despite my efforts of changing the color of my buttons, and reading everywhere on how to do it, my code still does not produce the desired effect. How can I change the color of a JButton
when clicked?

```
public void generateButtons
{
  //Global field
  firstBoard = new JButton[9][9];

        for(int x = 0; x < firstBoard.length; x++)
        {
            for(int y = 0; y < firstBoard[0].length; y++)
            {
                firstBoard[x][y] = new JButton();
                firstBoard[x][y].setActionCommand("0|" + (x + (firstBoard.length * y)));
                firstBoard[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                //firstBoardPanel.add(firstBoard[x][y]);
            }
        }
}

@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton )
        {
            System.out.println(parseActionCommand(((JButton)e.getSource()).getActionCommand()));
            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.BLUE); 
            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setContentAreaFilled(false);
            ((JButton)e.getSource()).setOpaque(true); 
        }
    }
```

Comment: Having run your code, it works just fine for me.  What look and feel are you using?  I've tried Windows, Metal and Nimbus and they all work just fine

Comment: I'm running on a mac, it's probably that look and feel.

Comment: Ah, yep, can't test that :P

Comment: I've dumped my test code as an answer, I want you to try using the default look at feel (Mac), which the base code is setup for and then try using the `Nimbus` look and feel, which is explained in the answer itself - sorry, I don't have access to a Mac right now to do my own testing :P

Comment: Also, did you mean to comment out the add line: `//firstBoardPanel.add(firstBoard[x][y]);`?

Comment: @MadProgrammer That seems to be a good observation

Comment: @MadProgrammer yeah, I did :p it was for something else I'm doing in the program. THank you though. It was the Mac look and feel that was messing with my code.

Comment: I'll have to wait to get home before I can see if I can find a way around it, but at least we narrowed it down

Comment: @MadProgrammer well I managed to get around it by changing the look and feel. I just changed the look and feel to the cross platform option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>**This is not an answer, but an extended test case to test the difference between Mac OS Look and Feel and Nimbus, which when run on Windows OS, works**</strike>

It appears, this became an answer...

Try this to start with...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ChangeButton {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ChangeButton();
    }

    public ChangeButton() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

        private final JButton[][] firstBoard;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(9, 9));
            firstBoard = new JButton[9][9];

            for (int x = 0; x < firstBoard.length; x++) {
                for (int y = 0; y < firstBoard[0].length; y++) {
                    firstBoard[x][y] = new JButton();
                    firstBoard[x][y].setActionCommand("0|" + (x + (firstBoard.length * y)));
                    firstBoard[x][y].addActionListener(this);
                    add(firstBoard[x][y]);
                }
            }
        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if (e.getSource() instanceof JButton) {
                System.out.println((((JButton) e.getSource()).getActionCommand()));
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setBackground(Color.BLUE);
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setContentAreaFilled(false);
                ((JButton) e.getSource()).setOpaque(true);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then replace `UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());` with this...

```
for (LookAndFeelInfo info : UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
    if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
        break;
    }
}
```

And try again

Answer (score 1):

Try repainting the container which contains that button.

```
button.getParent().validate();
button.getParent().repaint();
```

Comment: `revalidate` would be a better method and when I tested it using Windows, Metal and Nimbus look and feels, it wasn't required...

Answer (score -1):

Dont directly use the `e.getSource()` you need to reference it to an Object first and this use it:

**example:**

```
ublic void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
{
    Object ob = e.getSource();
    if(ob instanceof JButton )
    {
        System.out.println(parseActionCommand(((JButton)e.getSource()).getActionCommand()));
        JButton button = ((JButton)ob);
        button.setBackground(Color.BLUE); 
        button.setContentAreaFilled(false);
        button.setOpaque(true); 
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't change anything. It still doesn't change the color.

Comment: @AlanW and it prints?? upon clicking the button?

Comment: *"Dont directly use the e.getSource() you need to reference it to an Object first and this use it"* ... Why?

Comment: @MadProgrammer I once had the problem before.. And it was fixed by referencing it to an object first and use it